# Firebase showing "continue sdk setup"

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

I have created an android project in firebase but even after doing the first 3 steps I skipped the last step "if your app contacts our servers"
[A screenshot is attached here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yfN5a.png)
Also is my app registered or not how to check it?

Comment: Most probably, your app would have registered properly in the project. You can just make a write to Firestore to make a check if everything is working properly. Although, the easiest way to connect to firebase in the android studio is to just use the android studio assistant. Let me know, if something goes wrong :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well to complete that step in firebase you have to uninstall your app from your mobile device and reinstall it.